# Erro ao executar void start()

Tags: javafx, drawing

Boas, estava a realizar alguns codigos dos exercicios propostos. Quando fui executar deume o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized

at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)

at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)

at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:83)

at bluej.runtime.ExecServer.runOnTargetThread(ExecServer.java:902)

at bluej.runtime.ExecServer.access$700(ExecServer.java:78)

at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:767)
```

e agora qualquer que seja o programa que tente executar dá esse erro.

Comment: disponibilize o código para  que alguém possa testar.

Comment: Já tentou reiniciar a maquina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver parece que o problema está no ficheiro em si,ou seja, criando um novo projeto e copiando os mesmos codigos vai dar tudo certo.